# How to suppress processing message during code externalization in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

RStudio version 0.98.1028
My original markdown is 'Parent.Rmd'. I am creating a ioslides using it. I use following chunks:

````
```{r stp1, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', fig.path='figure/', progress=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)
```


```{r stp2, echo=FALSE}

knit_patterns$set(all_patterns[["md"]])
purl("parent.Rmd")
knit_patterns$set(all_patterns[["rnw"]])
read_chunk("parent.R")
```
````

But get the processing message in output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the chunk option `include = FALSE` if you do not want to include any output from the code chunk. Or if you prefer typing more characters, use `echo = FALSE, results = 'hide'`. Or if you prefer typing even more to silence the code chunk, `echo = FALSE, results = 'hide', message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig.show = 'hide'`. Hopefully now you see the point of a single chunk option `include = FALSE`.